# How to avoid using the IN clause in sql query used in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a better way to write the SQL other than using the IN clause in the below given SP. When i am using this IN clause, i suffer a performance dip due to large number or records involved in the User and Member tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MemberIdsFromUserIds] @dtUserIds UNIQUETABLE readonly
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT userID,
             Memberid
      FROM   Member
             INNER JOIN USER
               ON UserMemberID = MemberiD
      WHERE  userID IN (SELECT UniqueId
                        FROM   @dtUserIds)
  END
```

Kindly suggest the alternative as i don't have a full knowledge in writing SP

Comment: The query is fine. Probably you are missing some indexes. What indexes do you have? What does the execution plan look like? What is the definition of the table type? How many rows are you passing in in `@dtUserIds`?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I am having index on userid and memberid. The table will be a DataTable [From ADO.Net]. I will pass 25000 rows in the table. Kindly suggest a best solution if any

Comment: What is the definition of the `UNIQUETABLE` type? Do you have a `primary key` on `userID`? Also you may be getting a bad plan due to cardinality estimates on the TVP. You could try with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to see if you get a plan better suited for 25K rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith: The `userId` are uniqueidentifier datatypes. I have userId as primary key in usertable and so with the case of memberid. shall i use the `option(recompile)` in the stored procedure.

Comment: Yes add it to the end of the query and see if that improves things. If it does and you are always going to be passing in large numbers of rows you might want to then look at the plan you get and use other query hints to get the same plan without needing to recompile every time (but this will also mean that the plan won't adjust to cardinality changes in the other tables involved)

Comment: No matter what you do, it may be difficult to tune this query -- if the incoming table has 25k rows, unless the other tables are enormous, the plan that's going to be optimal will probably involve big range scans (it's probably *really* slow due to a nested loops plan right now). Are you sure you have to pass in 25k rows? Should the application be doing paging, or some other type of just-in-time query instead?

Comment: @JonSeigel: We are using this as part of the Bulk User Management process Jon, so we have to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Where exists is gnerally faster than IN

```
SELECT userID,
             Memberid
      FROM   Member
             INNER JOIN [USER]
               ON UserMemberID = MemberiD
      WHERE  EXISTS  (SELECT *
                        FROM   @dtUserIds a where [user].userId = a.Uniqueid)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this option, there is a half-chance that SQL Server will behave differently...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MemberIdsFromUserIds] @dtUserIds UNIQUETABLE readonly
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  userID,
        Memberid
    FROM  Member
    INNER JOIN USER
        ON UserMemberID = MemberiD
    INNER JOIN @dtUserIds
        ON UniqueId = userID
END
```

If this does not help, than please post all 3 tables' structures
(user, memeber and @dtUserIds) - including indexes and keys.

good luck :)

Comment: This is a simple query. Why would you expect the inner join being faster than an IN? What would be the chance that the execution plan would be different using this writing?

Comment: @Marian I do not EXPECT it to be faster, saravanan asked for a way to avoid using the IN clause, and this is an option which is easy to read as well. There is a chance however, that this WILL be faster under certain circumstances, influenced by table definitions, data distribution, statistics etc. where the difference will show in the execution plan (query plan) e.g. when "number of executions" of the IN clause will be high due to the use of nested loops, and an inner join will use a different method.

Answer (score -2):

```
Create proc demo
@A_C varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
EXEC ('select * from table1 where AC_No in ('+@A_C+')')
END

EXEC demo'321101030249,321101030268'
```